# PG unexpected behaviour with CTE and DML statements

Tags: postgresql

I have stumbled upon this, for keeping the problem easy to explain i have put a sample code below

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTab"
(
    "Id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Anukram"."MyTab_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "Text1" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Text2" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "MyTab_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
)
```

**Data Fill:**

```
INSERT INTO "Anukram"."MyTab" ("Text1","Text2") values
('L','R'),('A','B'),('C','D'), ('L','R1'),('A','B1'),('C','D1')
```

**Statement in Question:**

```
WITH "Temp" AS (
    UPDATE "MyTab"
    SET "Text2"="Text2" || "Text2"
    WHERE "Text1"='L'
    RETURNING *
)
DELETE 
FROM "MyTab"
USING "Temp"-- <--This is used in some more conditions in where clause not shown here
WHERE "MyTab"."Text1"='L'
RETURNING "MyTab".*
```

**Expectation**:

It should delete 2 rows with 'L' in "Text1" col

**Actual**:

It deletes just one row(looking at RETURNING statement)

**Observation**:

If i remove Using clause everything behaves as expected

So what am i missing here? or is this a bug in snapshots used by PG?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's still weird though, [I can](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fcd7e0517f023fc8f5db24a6f6d92f0f) [reproduce the problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fed200b9291bce3a5757a8ebb8556656)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific outcome in this case is surprising, but the underlying problem [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not supported. Only one of the modifications takes place, but it is not easy (and sometimes not possible) to reliably predict which one. This also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same statement: only the update is performed. Therefore you should generally avoid trying to modify a single row twice in a single statement. **In particular avoid writing `WITH` sub-statements that could affect the same rows changed by the main statement or a sibling sub-statement. The effects of such a statement will not be predictable.**

(Emphasis mine.)

In short: don't try to `UPDATE` and `DELETE` the same row in the same statement, else strange things may happen.

Comment: That still doesnt explain why, after commenting Using everything works as expected?(everything is still one statement) ..

Comment: I can't explain exactly why (would have to go into it with a debugger), but it may affect the execution order, so the "not predictable" works out in some other fashion.